# How can I install bertopic using anaconda prompt when i am getting error

Tags: installation-package

I am trying to install bertopic package. while installing this I am getting error

` building 'hdbscan._hdbscan_tree' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for hdbscan
Failed to build hdbscan
ERROR: Could not build wheels for hdbscan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`
this is the error i am getting.

I am using python version 3.8.8 and i am installing this package using anaconda prompt. My conda version is 4.10.1. I am already having Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 installed.

I am using 'pip install bertopic' command to install bertopic package.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by installing the python-dev package for the version of python I was using.

So on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.8-dev
```